# How can I prevent failing Livewire 3 tests outputting the whole page html?

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewire-3

When creating a basic test using Laravel 10 and Livewire 3, if the test fails, a
significant amount of HTML is output to the console as part of the failure. All to tell me that some string isn't in the HTML.

An example might be

```php
public function testExample(): void
{
   $this->get('/example')->assertSeeLivewire(SomeComponent::class);
}
```

Whilst writing tests if one happens to fail, I must wait up to 1-2 minutes for all this markup to scroll past in my console. For some reason I cannot CTRL+C in the PHP Storm Terminal window to close the process.

Is is possible to restrict or remove this output to make test creation quicker and easer? I do not want to use `-q` as this silences all output, even the error I might need to fix.